# Handling Errors from REST Services in C#

Tags: c#, rest

If I call a REST Web Service using this unix tool called CURL and there is a error in my call, the CURL program gives error messages very nicely

[image]

Now when I call the same REST Web Service from C# and I make the same mistake. The Exception which my code receives does not contain the same details like "summary", "details", "Message"

[image]

I have looked into "inner Exception" and "message" and "Stack Trace" propreties... but I cannot find the same level of information as the CURL tool.

Do you know how can I extract the same error information?

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you getting a webexception and catching it elsewhere? You can get the response stream from a webexception which will contain the json data you see.

Comment: Screenshot above itself has troubleshooting tip, if you want to check actual exception view InnerException & its message, description & place of occurrence...

Comment: No pranav. inner exception has nothing.

Crad gave the right suggestion. I should catch WebException rather than Exception and then parse the Json details and I get everything which I need.